# adding only 10 first objects to my array from an api that returns an array of 250 objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hey guys I have an api call that returns an array of 250 objects but I only want the first 10 objects stored in my array

```js
 useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://tennis-live-data.p.rapidapi.com/rankings/ATP', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
                setTop10([...top10, response.results.rankings[i]])
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))},[])
```

I tried doing this but it is not working, it's only adding the 10th object

Comment: Where does `top10` get a value? What does `setTop10()` do?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn’t use state setter functions (such as `setTop10`) in a loop. You should firstly create your array of data that you want to set, and then set your state. At the moment, your issue is that `top10` doesn't change after each iteration (it only changes on the next rerender), so you're not accumulating your `top10` state.

An alternative is to use `.slice()` to set your new state, assuming that `top10` stats off an an empty array/nothing:

```js
.then(response => {
  setTop10(response.results.rankings.slice(0, 10));
})
```

If you want to continue using a loop, then you can create a new array, push to that, and then set your state

```js
.then(response => {
  const newState = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    newState.push(response.results.rankings[i]);
  }
  setTop10(newState);
});
```

Also consider if it is possible to change your API call to only give you the data that you need on the client side, and instead request for only 10 items in your API call if it allows for it.

Comment: first thanks for the answer, I know I can do it with slice but what if I needed a way to do it with a loop , I wanna know how you can keep pushing items to an array in react js

Comment: Ok, it’s not that clear why you need to use a loop as appears to slice(), but I’ve provided an example that uses a loop instead (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
        .then(response => {
            for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
                setTop10([...top10, response.results.rankings[i]])
            }
        })
```

I guess, this code is setting value to top10.

setTop10 function will set top10 with value of old top10, and add response.results.rankings[i] is what you want.

how about ?

```
        .then(response => {
            setTop10(response.results.rankings.slice(0,10))
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure top10 is array.
Example :

```
(const [top10, setTop10] = useState([]);
```

> Then use arrow to mention current array and new data.

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTop10(top10 => [...top10, response.results.rankings[i]])
}
```

Comment: While this may work, I wouldn’t suggest continuously spreading top10 on every iteration of the loop. The spread itself is an implicit loop. It would be better (as it’s more efficient) to create the array, and then set state once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice method to extract the first 10 object from API response array

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://tennis-live-data.p.rapidapi.com/rankings/ATP', options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                const topTen = response.results.rankings.slice(0, 10);
              
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))},[]);
enter code here
```

to print all 10 objects use foreach loop hope it helps

```
top10.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(`Item ${index + 1}: `, item);
});
```